# Why advice to change adviser is rarely or simply not advised to be used in academia?

Tags: discussion, subjective-question

In this forum, and in [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83895/4-years-in-phd-no-publications-and-adviser-keep-changing-my-research) I noticed, in general,  that changing advisors are regarded as something that is bad and very difficult to achieve? Why members with high reputation on this forum, spread such a false information? or is that usual in academia, so the cases that actually change advisors are the exception from a majority of the situations in PhD programs.
I see people dont understand this question.
User with high reputation points on this forum, claim that you should drop or change PhD program, instead of changing advisors.
they dont provide any source or proof to support their claims.
Whenver this problem is brought, they tend to vote for closing question or delate comments.

Comment: In many cases, it's very true information: as usual things change by country, institution, etc. Don't generalize.

Comment: I don't understand this question. The linked question seems to not back up the accusation at all.

Comment: I think this is really clear question @TobiasKildetoft People, users at this forum, advice others to NOT change advisor, to rather change program!!!

Comment: In the linked question, the OP has explained why changing advisor is not possible in the specific situation.

Comment: I think my question is about users with high reputation score at academia. They suggest OP that it is better and more likely to change or quite PhD than to change advisor

Comment: @SSimon: why are you suggesting members are spreading "false information"?

Comment: because I never find any information or condition in PhD programs, that if you change advisor you need to drop studies. @ZeroTheHero never, and I googled it, and read through, if someone can provide something  substantial.

Comment: Right, but you have also not backed up your claim that this is being claimed by members of this community.

Comment: hmmm. member of this community means, user that log in and create account,

Comment: I am starting to get the feeling that you either don't actually read what people write or is simply incapable of understanding basic English.

Comment: again, I dont understand on what you are referring @TobiasKildetoft you are not clear.

Comment: @SSimon In the post you link, the OP has already tried to change advisors and was blocked and threatened by his current advisor for doing so. There does not appear to be any support for the OP at that institution. Therefore, *in that instance* many people recommended that only a change of institution is possible. You don't provide any support for your own claims here except for this one bad example, and you seem to be reading the answers there as if they apply to all situations rather than that one specific situation.

Comment: Further, your responses here make no sense at all. Someone asked why you think people are spreading "false information" and you responded with a definition of what a "member of this community is." It is like somebody asked you what your favorite color is and you responded that you like cats - it suggests that you might be making accusations based on a language barrier.

Comment: @BryanKrause isnt that illegal? to prevent him do that?

Comment: @SSimon It isn't illegal to be a bad advisor or to be a poor institutional fit for a student.

Comment: @BryanKrause really? you are not protected by law, or some sort of contract?

Answer (score 2):

We say it because in the overwhelming majority of cases/countries it's true. If [Glassdoor](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/index.htm) ever start including reviews of academic supervisors, you will see some really scary stuff. The longer you stay in academia, the more you see. That is why we try to warn people.

Comment: isnt that illegal?to prevent you from changing advisor?

Comment: No-one officially prevents you. But also no-one can force a new advisor take you on, it's a voluntary task. Therefore no-one chooses to jeopardise their relationship with their colleagues for a lowly student they will never see again.

Comment: oh, so there is some kind of cultural barrier. but what if these advisors are not from same department?

Comment: It's less difficult, but I have seen people rejected because of this nonetheless. They are considered "too risky".